# Woocommerce discounts if cart has products

Tags: woocommerce

Is there a option to create a coupon discount if the cart has 3 specific products?

I tried different things in the standard Woocommerce plugin but this does not work.

Is there somebody who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php to do the above -

```
function apply_discount_in_woocommerce_cart() {
    $coupon_code = 'abc'; 
    if ( WC()->cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) ) return;

    $specific_products = array( 12, 13, 14 ); // Assume 3 products ids
    $all_products_count = 0;
    foreach ( $specific_products as $product_id ) {
        $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id );
        $in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );
        if ( $in_cart ) {
            $all_products_count++;
        }
    }
    // check all products count equals to 3 on not
    if( $all_products_count === 3 ) {
        WC()->cart->add_discount( $coupon_code );
        wc_print_notices();
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'apply_discount_in_woocommerce_cart', 99 );
```

And don't forget to replace dummy products ids in array with your specific products ids and Coupon code.

Comment: Thnx this works :), but if people know the coupon code they has discount on everything. Where can I protect this that only these 3 together has the discount?

Comment: @YoeriAchterbergen, In that case everytime you have to create one time coupon code dynamically and pass that coupon code on above function to apply for those products. And for create coupon you can follow this [link](https://gist.github.com/mikejolley/3969579) and make sure to change `update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'individual_use', 'yes' );` for one time use only. Can you please accept the answer for others will find as useful.